# Surveillance by mobile network provider

Tags: privacy, man-in-the-middle, mobile, surveillance, dpi

I am customer of Vodafone Germany as my mobile network provider. After extension of my RED S mobile contract i realized, that the option "Vodafone Secure Net" is enforced by the company without informing me beforehand. After calling the customer service i found out, that its free for 3 month and that they are not able to deactivate before.
For me this situation is not acceptable, because i don't want my network provider to monitor or even MITM attack my connections as stated [here (german source)](https://netzpolitik.org/2014/waschmaschine-im-netz-wie-telekom-und-vodafone-deep-packet-inspection-als-feature-verkaufen/). Even encrypted traffic is monitored:

> The upgrade is also designed to help detect likely sources of malware that is hidden within encrypted web traffic using a secure HTTPS address. Further, parents can monitor the online activity of their offspring through the Secure Net app.
>   [(source)](http://marketmettle.com/knowvodafone/8031-vodafone-flags-convergence-focused-secure-net-upgrade)

So my question, how does [Vodafone Secure Net](https://securenet.vodafone.co.uk/) or similar services affect the users privacy and / or security?

Comment: You can ask vodafone whether they log the mobile surfing info and tied to your phone ID to make it identifiable, i.e. you can make them answer your question under GDPR clause. 
https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-request-your-personal-data-under-gdpr/

Comment: @Mootmoot Thats a good idea, especially to get familiar with the tech details they are using.  Additionally I am concerned about future uses like censorship or the goverment bringing in a new law to force identifiable web use because the tech is already there.

Comment: Then you should use VPN. A good VPN will use its own DNS to prevent it being hijacked by the telco.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I assume that the service provides scanning of HTTP and HTTPS traffic)

If you are using a device via someone else's network you have **very little privacy.**

HTTPS is intended to address that (up to a point). However since you seem to have discovered this after the fact, it *strongly* suggests that Vodafone have access to configure your device / deploy certificates.

**You have no privacy from someone who controls the device you use.**

Security? That's way too broad to answer here :)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Security i meant in context of what new threats might be introduced by Vodafone using their surveillance tools.